# Runtime error" '$' is undefined after formatting pc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a project written in C# ASP.net. jQuery have worked well before format computer. I have reinstall windows 7 on pc then install VS 2012 again. I run project then give this error

> JavaScript runtime error '$' is undefined

I don't change anything. I referenced jQuery top of aspx file.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<style>
    .ui-datepicker-trigger { position:relative;top:0px ;left:2px ; height:16px;width:16px;vertical-align:middle; }
    /* {} is the value according to your need */
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
```

**SOLUTION**
I have found solution like this 
[image]

Comment: have you tried to open the js files directly (view the page source, and follow the link to the jquery-3.1.0.min.js file)?

Comment: Did you check the network in firebug? May be the JQuery is not loaded or the path is incorrect.

Comment: This code works before

Comment: I have use  _references.js in VS 2012. Can this make error

Comment: It doesn't matter if the code worked before. You need to watch the network traffic in your browser's developer tools and verify that it's loading the jQuery library correctly.

Comment: Like other suggested, Plz check whether your jquery-3.1.0.min.js file exists or try using jQuery() instead of $();

Comment: @OptimumCreative I have use jQuery() . Gave same error also

Comment: You seem to be ignoring those of us suggesting that you check your browser's network tools to make sure that jQuery gets loaded correctly.

Comment: @mason , I try no load js. Also css file is not loaded :(

Comment: Be specific. What error message do you see? Does the path to the .js file match what you expect it to be?

Comment: I have found solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your physical location of jQuery file.
or try to add CDN of jQuery as below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is work but  I want to work site by offline in company

Comment: Save file physical path and use like : <script src="~/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You should change the path of the jquery libs to relative like this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-ui-1.12.0.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> You then will have to make a folder(if it doesn't exist) named Scripts and subfolder(if it doesn't exist) named js and place your jquery libs inside.